# htaccess redirect for non-www both http and https

Tags: http, .htaccess, redirect, https

I'd like to have:

- `http://example.com` redirect to: `http://www.example.com`
- `https://example.com` redirect to: `https://www.example.com`

And anything that is `http://whatever.example.com` NOT append the www like `http://www.whatever.example.com`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Here’s an explanation:

1. The first condition tests if the HTTP header field *Host* has the required format (contains exactly one period).
2. The second condition tests if the concatenated value of the value of the *HTTPS* variable (values `on` and `off`) and `s` (so either `ons` or `offs`) is equal to `ons` and captures the `s`. This means if `%{HTTPS}s` evaluates to `ons`, the first matching group is `s` and empty otherwise.
3. The rule will match all requests as every string has a start (marked with `^`) and redirects them to the evaluated value of `http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}` if both conditions are true. Where `%1` is the first matching group of the previous condition (`s` if HTTPS and empty otherwise), `%{HTTP_HOST}` is the HTTP *Host* of the request and `%{REQUEST_URI}` is the absolute URL path that was requested.

Comment: Can you also explain this? It's kind of Chinese for me... the first line is for catching only 2-part host (like: example.com). What the second line does, and how?

Comment: Looks good, but is producing 500 internal error message for me.

Comment: On some hosts you will need to replace the second line with `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL}s ^on(s)|` for proper SSL detection.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this `RewriteCond` to your .htaccess file to catch SSL only - then do the same thing for standard http.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
```