# URL rewriting for different protocols in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I need help with url-rewriting in .htaccess.

So the issue is about different protocols: https and http. The main purpose of rewriting is to remove "www" from URL, but protocol should stay the same it was before.

For example, when I have URL like **http**://www.domain.com/request, it should be redirected to the **http**://domain.com/request. I resolve it with these rules:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But in case, when URL looks like **https**://www.domain.com/request it should be redirected to **https**://domain.com/request.

Unfortunately, the above rule will redirect to **http** regardless current protocol.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect for non-www both http and https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015159/htaccess-redirect-for-non-www-both-http-and-https)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I've missed this question during searching. Unfortuntely, that exapmle doesn't work. It redirects https:// domain.com/request to the http:// www.domain.com/request, instead of https:// www.domain.com/request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is fairly similar to the linked possible duplicate, but since that one forces `www` where you want to remove it, it might warrant a separate answer.

Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: An explanation of those above rules will definitely be very helpful as reference for people looking for www to non www redirection.

Comment: seriously, apache API creators... why not just have a variable like `HTTP_PROTOCOL`, and have the second argument follow the same pattern like all the other ones?

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_PROTOCOL} ^http$` or `RewriteCond %{HTTP_PROTOCOL} ^https$` instead of making an exception to the rule? Less knowledge requirements is better. Extra knowledge is good, but extra required knowledge is bad. And you have to know the exact syntax and value. Who is going to guess `^on(s)|off`. Freaken old PHP-related tools...

Comment: brilliant answer (compliments the DigitalOcean documentation on redirecting www) although for maximum compatibility with case sensitivity `[NC]` should be set on the RewriteCond see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5582488/614616

Comment: Since Apache 2.4 there is now the REQUEST_SCHEME variable available, i.e.
%{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%{HTTP_HOST}/