# .htaccess all to index + www to non-www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a simple .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

and now would like to add redirect from all www cals to non www

how to combine it with my file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL rewriting for different protocols in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634101/url-rewriting-for-different-protocols-in-htaccess)

Comment: Put redirects *before* internal rewrites.

Comment: There is no rule shown here to do `www -> non-www` redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yourdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your file (right below `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://$1/$1 [L,R=301]
```