# https setup through elasticbeanstalk aws for java application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have query regarding setup of https to java application..
I have create load balancer for elastic beanstalk and give permission to security group  handle traffic to https
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oac4x.png)

But when I write domain with https://www.example.com .it works with https,but when I type domain name webpage open but without https.
My question here is should i write .htacces code or something else in java web application to achieve automatically come https green lock when I enter domain name only?
please help I got stuck here. I am very new to aws.

Comment: Does the Java app have redirects in it?

Comment: can you please more specific? i have route traffic of loadbalancer listners and security group?? java app redirects it i am not getting it.. u mean .htaccess??

Comment: It sounds like you have a redirect in your Java code or on the apache server its self.  Here is an example answer about keeping the protocols the sames https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634101/url-rewriting-for-different-protocols-in-htaccess#3636461

Comment: code is not working in java  ------ >>>RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]