# htaccess force www to non-www with consideration of http or https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am really stuck at conversion of this beautiful htaccess script (rule) which force non-www to www url considering the http or https its perfectly working but I cant make it work opposite way from www to non-www can you please help me?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Thank you I am really stuck at those htaccess symbols!

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect for non-www both http and https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015159/htaccess-redirect-for-non-www-both-http-and-https)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For making `www to non-www` above code will not work because of the way variable capturing works in RewriteCond. You need to break them into 2 rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```