# htaccess force https and redirect non www to www if not have a subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to force https and redirect non-www to www:

- domain.com      ==> https://www.domain.com
- www.domain.com  ==> https://www.domain.com

The problem is I have many sudomains and I don't have wildcard ssl (for now) so I want :

- (x).domain.com (except www.domain.com) ===> http://*.domain.com

Is that possible ?

All the ansewers i found and tested only force https or redirect all non-www to www my problem is i don't want subdomains get https except for www and redirect non-www to www

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess force https and redirect www to non-www, but no other subdomains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467329/htaccess-force-https-and-redirect-www-to-non-www-but-no-other-subdomains)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To force https://www only for the www.example.com , you can use :

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect http non-www to https://www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
#redirect https non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thank you starkeen that what i was looking for, can you plz explain to me this line => RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$

Comment: This is condition for the rule, it says host value must start with **www.** or **example.com** the pattern `(www\.)?` matches "www." optionally.