# Redirecting URL always from www to non-www with SSL/HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a SSL certificate for non www URL: `https://example.com`

I know there are many similar question, but none of them seems to solve my problem. Here is what I am trying to do:

**Problem:**

```
1) http://www.example.com -> https://example.com **www to non www DONE**

2) http://example.com -> https://example.com **http to https DONE**
```

So far, my .htaccess file looks like so:

```
# www to non www
# http to https
# SSL off
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# https://www to https://
```

Does anyone know the solution? With the current solution, I only get the following error message from the browser:

> Corrupted Content Error
>
> The site at http://example.com/ has experienced a network protocol
>   violation that cannot be repaired.
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in
>   the data transmission was detected.
>
> ```
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
> ```

Here are the solutions that I already tried:

- [.htaccess redirect www to non-www with SSL/HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478173/htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-ssl-https)
- [htaccess force https and redirect www to non-www, but no other subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467329/htaccess-force-https-and-redirect-www-to-non-www-but-no-other-subdomains)
- MANY MORE

Answer (score 0):

Change your rules to this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # https://www and http://www to https://non-www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # http://non-www to https://non-www
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I now have the following error `The page isn’t redirecting properly`. It looks like he's trying 21 times to pass me on. I use FireFox. Chrome says `example.com redirected you too many times.` as error. What is wrong?