# Redirect all traffic to https:// non-www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

I have tried several different redirect configuration in .htaccess to redirect all traffic to the https non-www URL of my site but can't get https://www.example.com to redirect to https://example.com.

To be clear I want:

```
    http://example.com
    http://www.example.com
    https://www.example.com
```

to redirect to

```
    https://example.com
```

http to https://example.com works fine

EDIT:

I can't remember the various combinations I used.

This is what I have set at the moment

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Note I have been through several other answered questions on stack overflow and none of the solutions has worked for me. This is affecting Firefox, IE and Safari. Chrome works fine.

Comment: Why not do it at the hosting level instead?

Comment: You should really show us what you actually tried. _“Note I have been through several other answered questions on stack overflow and none of the solutions has worked for me.”_ - well then it would be pointless for people to suggest the usual solutions now again. So what _should_ we suggest now, since you are so unspecific?

Comment: _“This is affecting Firefox, IE and Safari. Chrome works fine.”_ - this should not be browser dependent in the first place. Make sure that you are not just getting fooled by older, faulty redirects these browsers might have _cached_ already.

Comment: I cleared the cache every time I tried a different redirect setting

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# match any URL with www and rewrite it to https without the www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# match urls that are non https (without the www)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34333450/6479153).

Comment: @slarge check new version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to better understand your answer. Would you be willing to describe what each line is doing?

Answer (score 0):

I had problems on a domain where Safari refused to redirect from http to https using

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

I now have this working .htaccess content:

```
#  Force https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# remove www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```