# php .htacess redirect non www to www url not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect non www to www urls,its working fine except 
http://wellnessvisit.com/blog/

i want to redirect this to 
 http://www.wellnessvisit.com/blog/

while its working fine on all other urls but not working for this

below is my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule doctor-(.*)\.htm$ doctor-details.php?doc_id=$1
RewriteRule hospital-(.*)\.htm$ hospital_detail.php?hosp_spec_id=$1
RewriteRule hotel-(.*)\.htm$ hotel_details.php?hotel_id=$1
RewriteRule destination-(.*)\.htm$ destination_details.php?dest_id=$1
RewriteRule news-(.*)\.htm$ news-details.php?news_id=$1
RewriteRule article-(.*)\.htm$ articles-details.php?article=$1
RewriteRule service-(.*)\.htm$ service-details.php?service_id=$1
RewriteRule user-register.php$ register.php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
#adds ".php" to a URL that isn't a directory or a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[^./]+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: I think, you did the redirect correctly. There is an old answer about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050590/redirect-non-www-to-www-in-htaccess. Maybe, something else is wrong?

Comment: That single www rule looks fine to me. Did not check the rest though, since the question is specific.

Comment: @user4035 where is wrong?i did not add any condition in my code,this is complete mt .htaccess file

Comment: @user4035 there is two .htaccess file one at the root and 2nd in blog

Comment: @user4035 i modify and save the blog .htaccess file now when i click on blog its redirecting to index page.i don't know why its happening

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect for non-www both http and https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015159/htaccess-redirect-for-non-www-both-http-and-https)

Answer (score 0):

When I click http://wellnessvisit.com/blog/, it redirects me to http://www.wellnessvisit.com/blog/. So the htaccess rules seems to be working fine.

The issue you face maybe due to cached redirects, try the above link in another browser or try clearing your browser's cache.