# .htaccess always redirect non-www to www except subdomains?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I searched before posting this but couldn't find a topic that fits my needs. My site is `https only` and I want to always redirect any request of `https://domain.com` to `https://www.domain.com` .. EXCEPT when somebody accesses `https://username.domain.com` then I need it redirected to `https://www.domain.com/user?username=...`

Right now I have it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?)\.(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.domain.com/user?username=%1 [L,QSA]
```

But it's not working with the non-www redirect to www. What part do I need to change and how?

I checked the other answer but it doesn't work as soon as I add the /user? rule...

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect for non-www both http and https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015159/htaccess-redirect-for-non-www-both-http-and-https)

Comment: Yes, I know. Except the last rule. That's why I couldn't get it working. It's stuck in an endless loop if I add the last rule. It's working if I don't add it, however.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your rules as this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com/user?username=%1 [L,QSA,R=302]
```