# .htaccess redirect from one domain to another including subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two domains, for example:

- example.com
- website.co.uk

I want to redirect in the following ways:

- `example.com` **-->** `https://www.website.co.uk`
- `alt.example.com` **-->** `https://www.alt.website.co.uk`
- `test.example.com` **-->** `https://www.test.website.co.uk`

As you can see, I want it always to **force** `https` **and** `www.`

But, I also want it to remember the rest of the URL strcture, for example:

- `example.com/folder/index.html` **-->** `https://www.website.com/folder/index.html`
- `alt.example.com/test/` **-->** `https://www.alt.website.com/test/`
- `test.example.com/o/index.php` **-->** `https://www.test.website.com/o/index.php`

I'm not sure the best way for this to be done, the two options I found were to try rewrite rules and the other was a 301 redirect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess redirect for non-www both http and https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015159/htaccess-redirect-for-non-www-both-http-and-https)

Comment: (yes, the duplicate preserves the protocol instead of forcing https, but this is the simpler case of the two. Just remove the condition and set the protocol to https)

Comment: No, not a duplicate of that because I want it to force the www and https because otherwise there will be 3 redirects as my main site already forces www and https

Comment: There is only 1 redirect in the linked question. It is not a perfect duplicate, but the changes are soo minor that I feel like I have to plagiarize the answers there to answer this question. If you understand the directives there, the changes to make your requirements work should be trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following  rules

```
RewriteEngine on


#redirect subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.domain2.com/$1 [L,R]

#redirect domain

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [L,R]
```